# Is it possible to rename files in Explorer and check-in them all into TFS simultaneously?

Tags: tfs, file-rename

I need to rename large amount of files in different folders.

The main problem is that TFS server is located across the ocean (i.e. very far away and working with it is slow), so renaming each file turn by turn is very slow.

How can I automate renaming? If I were using TortoiseSVN I could rename all this files in Windows Explorer and commit them simultaneously. How can I do that in TFS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all:  Be very careful renaming files in TFS.  This is a somewhat delicate operation.  Make sure to check in and merge as soon after you do the rename as possible.

That being said.  If you can rename the files in Explorer, you can use the TFS Shell Extensions to do the checkins.  The shell extensions are part of the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx).